# How can I enter this formula in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR4lb.png)

I have the following formula for e' in which e'i always refers to the previous result of e'i-1. At the beginning there is a boundary condition for e' i=1. How can I enter this to get a matrix with all values?

i = 1 - 30

In Matlab I managed it with a For loop

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
eprime[1]=boundary;
For[i=2,i<=4,i++,
  eprime[i]=e[i]/(d[i]-c[i]*eprime[i-1])==
  (-dt a/dx^2)/((2 dt a/dx^2+1)-(-dt a/dx^2)*eprime[i-1])]
```

then

```
eprime[4]
```

returns

```
e[4]/(d[4] - c[4]*(e[3]/(d[3] - c[3]*(e[2]/(-(boundary*c[2]) + d[2]) == -((a*dt)/
((1 + (2*a*dt)/dx^2 + (a*boundary*dt)/dx^2)*dx^2)))) == -((a*dt)/(dx^2*(1 + (2*a*dt)/
dx^2 + (a*dt*(e[2]/(-(boundary*c[2]) + d[2]) == -((a*dt)/((1 + (2*a*dt)/dx^2 +
(a*boundary*dt)/dx^2)*dx^2))))/dx^2))))) == -((a*dt)/(dx^2*(1 + (2*a*dt)/dx^2 + 
(a*dt*(e[3]/(d[3] - c[3]*(e[2]/(-(boundary*c[2]) + d[2]) == -((a*dt)/((1 + (2*a*dt)/
dx^2 + (a*boundary*dt)/dx^2)*dx^2)))) == -((a*dt)/(dx^2*(1 + (2*a*dt)/dx^2 + (a*dt*
(e[2]/(-(boundary*c[2]) + d[2]) == -((a*dt)/((1 + (2*a*dt)/dx^2 + (a*boundary*dt)/
dx^2)*dx^2))))/dx^2)))))/dx^2)))
```

Then you can raise the limit on that For up to 20 and assign values to any of the things that you know and see what the result looks like.